# Locale independent year week date format

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, java-time

I want to print an `Instant` in a locale independent way, with ISO settings for first day of week (Monday) and minimal days in first week (4).

My current setup is:

```
private String print(Instant i) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("YYYY-ww")
            .withZone(UTC);
    return formatter.format(i);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.format("First day of week      : %s%n",
            WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).getFirstDayOfWeek());
    System.out.format("Min days in 1st week   : %s%n",
            WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek());
    Instant instant = Instant.parse("1998-12-31T00:00:00Z");
    System.out.println(print(instant));
}
```

For system locale "en_US" the test prints:

```
First day of week      : SUNDAY
Min days in 1st week   : 1
1999-01
```

For system locale "de_DE" the test prints:

```
First day of week      : MONDAY
Min days in 1st week   : 4
1998-53
```

The "de_DE" locale is consistent with ISO settings and I know I could set up my formatter as

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("YYYY-ww")
        .withZone(UTC)
        .withLocale(Locale.GERMANY);
```

but can I do that without specifying any locale bound to a particular country? I've found `java.time.temporal.WeekFields#ISO`:

```
public static final WeekFields ISO = new WeekFields(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 4);
```

which is what I want, but I don't know how to combine it with the `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Accoring to DateTimeFormatter's documentation, "If [withZone is] overridden, the date-time value is converted to a ZonedDateTime with the requested ZoneId before formatting. During parsing the ZoneId is applied before the value is returned". So I think what happens is that the parsing creates a US local time, then rezones to UTC during formatting.

Comment: @daniu I initially thought the same as you, but now I think it's not related to the zoneId. Even if I create a formatter without zone (`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-ww")`) and use it to format a `LocalDate` (which has no timezone information), the output also changes for each locale. The behaviour of week fields `Y` and `w` seems to be  really locale specific, regardless of the timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and the respetive fields of `WeekFields.ISO`:

- **week-based-year** (which is the [equivalent of `Y` pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-))
- **week-of-week-based-year** (which is the [equivalent of `w` pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-))

The code is:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // append week year
    .appendValue(WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear(), 4)
    // separator
    .appendLiteral('-')
    // append week of week year field
    .appendValue(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 2)
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter().withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

And instead of creating a new `WeekFields` instance (with `WeekFields.of(locale)`), just use `WeekFields.ISO` instead:

```
System.out.format("First day of week      : %s%n", WeekFields.ISO.getFirstDayOfWeek());
System.out.format("Min days in 1st week   : %s%n", WeekFields.ISO.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek());
Instant instant = Instant.parse("1998-12-31T00:00:00Z");
System.out.println(formatter.format(instant));
```

The output is:

> First day of week      : MONDAY
>   Min days in 1st week   : 4
>   1998-53

---

Even if I change the locale of the formatter:

```
formatter = formatter.withLocale(Locale.GERMANY);
```

Or:

```
formatter = formatter.withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

The output stays the same.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for! A small improvement, though: use `.appendLiteral('-')` instead of `.appendPattern("-")` and specify the width of the year and week parts using `.appendValue(WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear(), 4)` and `.appendValue(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 2)`.

Comment: @AdamMichalik You're welcome! Indeed, I forgot about the width of the fields. And using `appendLiteral` is really clearer in this case. I've updated the answer, thanks!